# How to create dynamic column names in sql server

Tags: sql-server, variables, dynamic

I need to generate column names dynamically based on today's date.

```
DECLARE @var1 nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @var3 nvarchar(max)
set @var1= 'Overall_'+substring(convert(varchar,convert(date,getdate())),9,2)+'_'+FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM')
set @var3='select [SOURCE],sum(value)/100000 as '+@var1 + ' into #temp1 from jan_ivn group by [SOURCE]' 
exec sp_executesql @var3
```

when I execute @var3 I get the desired results. But when I set @var3 into a table (#temp1) and 
run #temp1 it is showing that #temp1 is invalid object name.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: A tempoorary object only exists for the connection/scope that created it. A temporary object create in a dynamic statement is stop persisting when that statement ends. Also, you to parametrise and properly quote when using Dynamic SQL. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: @ Максим Золотенко. Thanks.

Comment: Use `##temp1` instead of `#temp1`:)